# MCreator: Can't find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently working on a new mod named "Craftelmon", which adds the 9th Generation Pokémon into Minecraft. But every time when I'm saving a mod element inside MCreator, the Editor shows around 820 errors and unfortunately, I can't fix them because I'm not very good in java coding. I don't have logs. The error is mostly "Can't find symbol". Can someone please help me fix the errors?

Sincerely yours,
Mika Kreis

Answer (score -1):

"Cannot find symbol" most refers to variables that have not been declared and or classes or packages that have not been declared and imported into the file.
Meaning it does not understand and cannot find its class or type or package name, although there is some name token for something in the code, but it's indefinable, maybe out of scope as a rare error.